# ffmpeg waits to close the pipe in order to start processing data

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm struggling with this issue.
Here I am trying to stream video using ffmpeg from images and audio file  this code below works fine but it is start streaming after stdin closed, I would expect ffmpeg to start processing the pipe input as it is received, and immediately output the result.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
    [
        'ffmpeg',
        '-y',
        '-re',
        '-f', 'image2pipe',
        '-vcodec', 'mjpeg',
        '-framerate', '15',
        '-analyzeduration', '2147483647',
        '-probesize', '2147483647',
        '-i', '-',
        '-vn', '-i', audio_path,
        '-c:v', 'libx264',
        '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
        '-preset', 'ultrafast',
        '-c:a', 'aac',
        '-f', 'flv',
        rtmp_url
    ],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)

time.sleep(2)

i = 0
while True:
    current_images = [name for name in os.listdir(img_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(img_dir, name))]
    current_images = sorted(current_images)
    if i > fnum-1:
        print("frame read failed")
        break
    try:
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(img_dir, current_images[i]))
        success, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
        frame = buffer.tobytes()
        p.stdin.write(frame)
        i += 1
    except:
        time.sleep(2)
        pass

p.stdin.close()
p.wait()
```

Why is ffmpeg waiting to close the pipe to start processing? Can it be configured to start a live transcoding of the received stream?

Do you know how can I convince ffmpeg to start producing output immediately?

Thank you!

Comment: It shouldn't, but it does not immediately start producing output frames. It takes in a first few frames to analyze before outputting its first frame. How many frames have you tried to input? (side note: I hope the code is for illustration purpose only as it makes a little sense to use opencv to read the file like that...)

Comment: @kesh I am trying to read 800 frames, but it takes all frames to analyze before outputting anything!

Comment: @MahmoudFerig Try without `'-analyzeduration', '2147483647'` and without `'-probesize', '2147483647'`.  You may also try adding argument `['-tune', 'zerolatency']` for reducing the latency.  And kesh is correct - it doesn't make sense to use `cv2.imread` then `cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)`. JPEG is a lossy codec, so you are loosing quality (and loosing execution time).

Comment: I removed them ``` '-analyzeduration', '2147483647', '-probesize', '2147483647' ``` and it works fine thank you @Rotem    and yes I edited the reading images way like Kesh said. Thank you, guys.